# How to calculate days, hours, minutes from now to certain date in swift

Tags: swift

Calculate the number of days, hours, minutes and seconds to another date in swift.

I have already tried using swifts datecomponents to and from function but it is returning the incorrect amount of days for me.

```
@objc func createCountdown(){
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)

    let currentDate = calendar.date(from: components)

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    var birthdayDate = DateComponents()
    //Get user's birthday
    birthdayDate.month = 4
    birthdayDate.day = 16
    birthdayDate.hour = 0
    birthdayDate.minute = 0


    let birthday = userCalendar.date(from: birthdayDate as DateComponents)


    let BirthdayDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate!, to: birthday!)

    let daysLeft = BirthdayDifference.day
    let hoursLeft = BirthdayDifference.hour
    let minutesLeft = BirthdayDifference.minute
    let secondsLeft = BirthdayDifference.second

    daysLabel.text = String(daysLeft!)
    hoursLabel.text = String(hoursLeft!)
    minutesLabel.text = String(minutesLeft!)
    secondsLabel.text = String(secondsLeft!)
}
```

The test date in the code is the birthday values. I'm simply trying to make a day, hour, minute, and second countdown to the specified birthday from the current date.

The output for this is 74 days, but obviously it is more than 74 days from today, 12/31/2018 to april 16th, 4/16/2019. That is around 105 days, not 74. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find out when is the next birth date based on the day and month of birthday. You can use Calendar's method `nextDate(after: Date, matching: DateComponents)`

```
func nextDate(after date: Date, matching components: DateComponents, matchingPolicy: Calendar.MatchingPolicy, repeatedTimePolicy: Calendar.RepeatedTimePolicy = default, direction: Calendar.SearchDirection = default) -> Date?
```

---

```
let birthDateCoponents = DateComponents(month: 4, day: 16)
let nextBirthDate = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: birthDateCoponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!

let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: nextBirthDate)

difference.day     // 105
difference.hour    // 2
difference.minute  // 5
difference.second  // 30
```

When displaying it to the user you can use DateComponentsFormatter with the appropriate `unitsStyle`. You can see below how it would look like when using `.full` style and limiting the units to `.day, .hour, .minute, .second`:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]

formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.string(from: Date(), to: nextBirthDate)  // "105 days, 1 hour, 44 minutes, 36 seconds"
```